# Python Crawler giving me a lot of syntax error

Tags: python, syntax, web-crawler

Can anyone help me compiling this python code in Python 3.3 ? I am getting a lot of error messages .

https://github.com/andronikov/tpb2csv

Thanks :)

Comment: How are you trying to "compile" this and what error messages are you seeing?

Answer (score 1):

That code is not compatible with Python 3, it works only on Python 2 (as can be seen from the fact that `print` is a statement, not a function in this code).

You can try using [2to3](http://docs.python.org/2/library/2to3.html) on it, but I expect a lot of manual work because the original code appears to be doing lots of Unicode string manipulation, and that part of the language has been completely overhauled in Python 3.

Oh, and it's using third-party libraries like BeautifulSoup's `UnicodeDammit`. This is not going to be easy.

Comment: Can you compile it for me ? Please ?

Comment: You should ask the original author to port it to Python 3. But why don't you use it on Python 2?

Comment: Which version of python do you think should I use to compile this ?

Comment: I don't know, I didn't write it. Try Python 2.7.3 and work your way backwards if it doesn't work. What do you mean by compiling? Python is an interpreted language. You need to install third-party libraries as well (BeautifulSoup at least). Better find the original documentation for this package...

Comment: You are right . I meant interpreting . Sorry for that :) I am on it . Thanks for the advice .